# How can I know the Apple Event Access Groups used by an application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox, appleevents

Apples' Sandobox is supposed to use Apple Event Access Groups, which allow applications to communicate with each other, as described in the WWDC video "[Session 206 Secure Automation Techniques In OS X](http://adcdownload.apple.com//videos/wwdc_2012__hd/session_206__secure_automation_techniques_in_os_x.mov)"

However, what is not mentioned (and I could find no reference to it in Xcode 5.x documentation) is **how** can I find out which Apple Event Access Groups are defined for a specific application.

For example, if I want my App to communicate with Pages (or Photoshop, or Firefox, etc.), how can I find documentation about its Apple Event Access Groups? Where are they defined, and what tool can I use to find them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apple Events from sandboxed apps is typically done with Apple Script. There is documentation for the entitlement needed here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW25

To find which app provides access groups is a bit of a hassle and there aren't many available. Use terminal and `sdef` to find out. this will give you an XML which you can read and look for access-group

eg in Console:

```
sdef /Applications/Mail.app > mail.sdef.xml
open mail.sdef.xml
```

Then you'll see the line

```
<access-group identifier="com.apple.mail.compose" access="rw"/>
```

Comment: I submitted a radar at Apple for a GUI for access groups. find a copy of it here http://www.openradar.me/14734642 and submit one as well please.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd upvote you, but the system tells me I don't have enough reputation points :-/ (I am new to Stack Overflow. This was my first question.)

Comment: It would be nice to have a better way of seeing an app's access groups, but don't sweat it too much. As far as I can tell, there are literally two apps in the entirety of Mavericks that include access groups (Mail and iTunes). Hopefully they'll improve this in future releases.

Comment: what if sdef a NOT apple app and it doesn't have <access-group identifier>?

Comment: @stanliu I just used this answer to discover the scripting targets for Spotify (com.spotify.client). So in 2020 at least, some non-Apple apps also provide this information in the sdef file. As the documentation suggests, using the com.apple.security.scripting-targets key in an entitlements file is preferable to com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events.