# How to run an AppleScript from a sandboxed application on a Mac (OS X)

Tags: cocoa, applescript, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

We are developing an application for the Mac App Store using Qt 5.2.0.Framework on MacOSX 10.9.

Here is a simple AppleScript that creates a Microsoft Excel workbook and saves to any location.

```applescript
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set myworkbook to make new workbook
    set fname to POSIX file "/Private/var/root/Download/ExcelFile" as text
    save workbook as myworkbook filename fname
end tell
```

The above script is saved as `Untitled.scpt` in `/Library/ApplicationScript/`.

Inside the application, we use the Cocoa framework to execute the AppleScript.

This AppleScript works in a non-sandboxed application. It fails in a sandboxed application.

My question is: How do you use an AppleScript in a sandboxed application? Or is there an alternative to this?

Kindly tell me the solution, because my project is being delayed by this.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've reformatted your question to make it more readable; please take a look at the source, so you can perform this formatting yourself in the future; You first say that the script filename is `new.scpt`, but your Objective-C code references `Untitled.scpt`. I know little about sandboxing, but I wouldn't expect paths such as `/private` and `/Library` to be writable from a sandboxed application. How is the `.scpt` file saved to the target location?

Comment: This,apple script save as Untitled.scpt (not new.scpt) in this path "/Library/ApplicationScript/Untitled.scpt".                       when execute the script using cocoa, excel file is created which save as /Private/var/root/Download/ExcelFile this location

Comment: replace keyword "new.scpt" to "Untitled.scpt" in my quection

Comment: This is a good post to read https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There two issues with your code:

- Excel probably doesn't yet support `com.apple.security.scripting-targets`, so you would need `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636464/how-can-i-know-the-apple-event-access-groups-used-by-an-application/21679279#21679279) how to find out if it supports it and here [how to work with the temporary exception](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW3) by adding an array of bundle-identifiers you want to target. You had that in the old screenshot of this question.)
- The entitlement of scripting-targets as well as for `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` is an array of bundle-identifiers. You would see it in Xcode like this: [image: com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events]
- A Mac App Store app must not install anything in shared locations like `/Library/ApplicationScript` (see [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html) Section 2.15). You need to store the Script inside your Container and run it from there.

Comment: I am not understand the key value for com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events or com.apple.security.scripting-targets in entitlement file. what is the correct value of this key. which execute the apple script on sand boxed application.

Comment: Thanks mahal  for solve the big problem of my project.

Comment: can not execute do shell script command using cocoa. cocoa code dummy is to see above my question. descriptor  variable for NSAppleEventDescriptor is return a NULL value. my script file is contain this command  "do shell script "diskutil info / | grep \"Volume Nmae:\"" "

Comment: this is a new question. to "do shell script" you would need to have another entitlement. And for diskutil you're better off doing it with Disk Arbitration https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Conceptual/DiskArbitrationProgGuide/ManipulatingDisks/ManipulatingDisks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009310-CH3-SW7

Comment: My Apple Script is successfully run on 10.7,10.8.5,10.9.but It fails in a Mountain Loin(10.8 to 10.8.4) . My apple script store in app  container. script path is -> "/Users/UserName/Library/Containers/com.comanyName.ProductName/Data/Library/AppleScripts/"

Comment: My project is delay because apple script is not run on 10.8 in sand-boxed application.

Comment: You probably have to work without 10.8 to 10.8.4 as this sandbox-implementation is full of bugs. Check when starting the App for the OS and ask user to update to 10.8.5.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [add the `com.apple.security.scripting-targets` sandboxing entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW25) to script other apps from within the sandbox.

Comment: I am new user on MAC,In entitlements ,i am create a new entry for com.apple.security.scripting-targets . but how to create application-group-id.

Comment: You just add the keys/values from the link above (it has an example) to your .entitlements file.

Comment: see the screen shot for entitlements file is attach to this question. Adding the scripting-targets key in sandbox application,but new created sandbox application is not execute the apple script.

Comment: `com.apple.security.scripting-targets` is not a boolean value, it's an array of strings. Please read the article I linked to.

Comment: script is not run after adding a new key com.apple.security.scripting in entitlement file. (see the second screen shot for entitlement file). If key value is wrong ,please tell me correct value and provide me a suitable example which solve the my problem.

Comment: My Apple Script is successfully run on 10.7,10.8.5,10.9.but It fails in a Mountain Loin(10.8 to 10.8.4) . My apple script store in app container. script path is -> "/Users/UserName/Library/Containers/com.comanyName.ProductName/Data/Library/Appl‌​eScripts/"

Comment: other alternative method which run apple script on 10.8 to 10.8.4 in sand-boxed application . but, In nonsand-boxed application my apple script is successfully run on 10.8 , means this is bug for apple script on sand-boxed application

Answer (score 1):

To work with Apple Script from your app you have to add the bundle identifiers of the app you want to send or receive events from in the entitlements file.

Here is the syntax:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
    <string>{bundle identifier of app 1}</string>
    <string>{bundle identifier of app 2}</string>
</array>
```

You can have one or multiples app bundle identifiers in that array. Now, these apps can receive your apple events commands.

Example:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.finder</string>
    <string>com.apple.systemevents</string>
    <string>com.microsoft.excel</string>
</array>
```