# reseting Finder from objective c/swift in sandbox

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, applescript

I'm trying to rest Finder from my code (in sandbox). One of the approaches that I tried is calling following apple script:

> tell application \"Finder\" to quit

but it doesn't seem to work on the Mavericks. Any ideas?

Comment: Turn off the sandbox for your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the **com.apple.security.scripting-targets** sandboxing entitlement to script other apps from within the sandbox. Please check
[How to run an AppleScript from a sandboxed application on a Mac (OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924932/how-to-run-an-applescript-from-a-sandboxed-application-on-a-mac-os-x)