# Control other app in my app(in sandbox)

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, sandbox, entitlements

I want to miniaturize the Finder in my app, so I use ScriptingBridge to control the Finder.
But, when my app is in the sandbox, it fails to run.

I added com.apple.security.scripting-targets in the sandbox entitlements. Here is the code

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
    <key>com.apple.finder</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.finder.compose</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: this 'compose' entitlement does not exist. see key answer on how to find targets.

Answer (score 1):

Finder does not have any scripting access groups. You could add the temporary exception `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` [as documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW1).

To find scripting targets see here: [How can I know the Apple Event Access Groups used by an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636464/how-can-i-know-the-apple-event-access-groups-used-by-an-application/21679279#21679279)

If you'd like to distribute your app in App Store, however, you're out of luck. By scripting Finder, your app will not pass the review into the App Store.