# How to using ScriptingBridge in the entitlements

Tags: objective-c, macos, appstore-sandbox, scripting-bridge

I wanna control 'Finder' in my app, so I can minimize Finder. I tried  ScriptingBridge, but it doesn't work in Sanboxed. But it works when the app is not sandboxed. So I check the Apple's developer documents, seems that I have to set com.apple.security.scripting-targets in entitlements when I need to use ScriptingBridge in sandbox. But it doesn't say anything about the setting, so what should I do in the setting in order to control finder? Thanks in advance.

here is  entitlements :
           com.apple.security.scripting-targets
        
           ???????
        
           ????

Comment: Can you post the scripting code you're trying to run?

Answer (score 2):

Finder does not have any scripting access groups. You could add the temporary exception `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` [as documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW1).

To find scripting targets see here: [How can I know the Apple Event Access Groups used by an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636464/how-can-i-know-the-apple-event-access-groups-used-by-an-application/21679279#21679279)

If you'd like to distribute your app in App Store, however, you're out of luck. By scripting Finder, your app will not pass the review into the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Finder does not have any scripting access groups on purpose, because it lets you dodge sandbox file system restrictions.  (As the other answer mentions, you could use the old `temporary-exception.apple-events` entitlement to script Finder anyway, but it won't pass store review.)  Try using `NSWorkspace` instead, in particular the `-openFile`, `-launchApplication`, and `-selectFile` methods.  If by "minimize" you really meant "hide", then see `-[NSRunningApplication hide]`.