# Get the current selection from macOS Finder

Tags: swift, mac-app-store, entitlements, scripting-bridge

It seems like the only way to get to the currently selected files/folders of the macOS Finder is via the Scripting Bridge. The [SwiftScripting](https://github.com/tingraldi/SwiftScripting) project provides some pre-generated extensions to use. The code is rather simple:

```
    public func getSelected() -> [NSURL] {

        guard let app = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.finder") else {
            print("no app")
            return []
        }
        
        let finder = app as FinderApplication
        guard let result = finder.selection else {
                print("No items selected")
                return []
        }

        print("result", result)

        guard let selection = result.get() else {
            print("get failed: ", result.lastError() ?? "")
            return []
        }

        print("selection", selection)

        return []
    }
```

But unfortunately the `get` of the selection fails

```
result <SBObject @0x600000d26310: selection of application "Finder" (6039)>
get failed:  Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-1743 "(null)" UserInfo={ErrorNumber=-1743}
```

That error is `errAEEventNotPermitted`. Which suggests the app needs the correct entitlements. The temporary exception would not be allowed on the App Store - but should in theory be enough. The scripting targets would probably the way to go - but it seems virtually [impossible to find the relevant docs](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=com.apple.security.scripting-targets) on this.

```
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.finder</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.finder</key>
        <array>
            <string>???</string>
        </array>
    </dict> 
</dict>
```

What parts am I missing to get this working?

**Update**:

What I was missing was the permission in the `Info.plist`. The key `Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description` needs to be set. That makes the `get` call succeed.

To get this through the app store review though, setting `com.apple.security.scripting-targets` correctly would still be required.

I am still looking for information on what target configurations are available for the Finder.

Comment: @vadian That does not seem to be quite correct. It's working for me now - even from the sandbox. But I would still need the correct scripting target entitlements to get this through the review.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment but the app will be rejected from App Store. `ScriptingBridge` is not allowed.

Comment: @vadian The temporary exception is no longer allowed. But I do have one on the App Store using the ScriptingBridge. But you will need to use the proper scripting target entitlements. And I just cannot find the right docs for the Finder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I know the Apple Event Access Groups used by an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636464/how-can-i-know-the-apple-event-access-groups-used-by-an-application)

Comment: To retrieve the currently selected files or folders from macOS Finder, you can use the Scripting Bridge and the SwiftScripting project to generate extensions but you will need to set the correct entitlements and permission in the Info.plist to get it to work. it may not be allowed in the app store review